# How to remove .html and add slash in the end of url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect

I have been trying to remove the .html extensions, and add a trailing slash in the end of URL bar.

I have certain instance like below

So if someone enters:

example.com             -- goes to-- example.com/

example.com/index.html  -- goes to - example.com/

example.com/index       -- goes to -- example.com/

and

example.com/first-page.html          -- goes to -- example.com/main-page/ **but coming as example.com/main-page**

example.com/parent-page/index.html   -- goes to -- example.com/parent-page/ **(working)**

example.com/parent-page/child-page.html/ -- goes to -- example.com/parent-page/child-page/ **but comes as example.com/parent-page/child-page**

Here is my .htaccess, I want add the trailing slash at the end of url.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html 

# Forces a trailing slash to be added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Any one could please help me out, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to remove the .html extension from an HTML file, for example, yoursite.com/wallpaper.html to yoursite.com/wallpaper you simply have to alter the last line from the code above to match the filename

### Removing Extensions .html

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

### Adding a trailing slash at the end

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

For more reference click [here](https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/)